# Website crashed every two months. App pool recycle fixes the issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

We have a ASP.NET 2.0 (i know it's old!) website hosted on a Windows 2003 server and IIS 6.0. The application periodically crashes after every two months.

We have tried to analyse the memory consumption and other things by using Telerik and very recently Riverbed.

Any idea what should we be looking for?

**UPDATE:** After searching the WWW I stumbled upon this a fix where they tell that we can increase the request queue limit to stop this issue. Although the root cause analysis is still desirable.

Comment: You should be looking for a higher version of ASP.net.

Comment: What is the automatic App pool recycle intervall set to, or is it disabled?

Comment: If the app pool recycle fixes the issue you should probably set the recycle intervall to less than 2 months

Comment: The app pool worker process recycle is set to 1440 mins. That's 24 hours. And still we see this error. :(

Comment: You'll want to look for leaking kernel objects as well, look for increasing handle usage over time.

Comment: @ChrisO Will riverbed or telerik help in that?

Comment: Not to mention Server 2003 is almost EOL - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/

Comment: Any resource monitor can help with tracking handle objects, not sure about those two products, they might.  You can use Windows' built-in Task Manager / perfmon to show Handles, though perfmon can track over time.

Comment: Will look for this. Thanks.